# Django PostgreSQL existing database does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a table `tablename` with schema `sub` in PostgreSQL that definitely exists--it has been created, it has had data added to it, and when I run `SELECT * FROM sub.tablename` in pgAdmin 4, it returns results without issue.

When I try to then access that same table in my Django application, it produces error `psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "main.sub.tablename" does not exist`. I attempted making the table name `sub.tablename` and `tablename` but it still claims the table does not exist. I am the owner of `sub` and it is my credentials used to access the table. I have confirmed that the host name and the port are what they should be.

I'm at a loss as to how to fix this since, as far as I can tell, this error only shows up when people haven't actually created the table yet or misspell something.

**ETA:** The point of connecting to PostgreSQL instead of just using the standard sqlite is in production I'll have a PostgreSQL table with usernames and passwords (like `tablename`) for logging in to the application. Not sure if that makes a difference here.

Below is my relevant code blurb in `settings.py` where the table/database info appears.

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'tablename',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '1234',
    }
}
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 178, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "opr.opr_user_test" does not exist
```

Comment: What are your migrations? They handle all of that for you. Have you created them for the appropriate models and migrated them?

Comment: I don't think Django will create a database fo us if it's not existing.

Comment: @Hanny Yes I run migrate when I build my app in a Docker container and that's when it triggers the table does not exist error.

Comment: @JPG Yes I know, but this table exists.

Comment: If it's saying it doesn't exist it most likely isn't there. When you're building your Docker, are you rebuilding the DB & table? Is your DB persisting when you're shutting down Docker and re-building it? Perhaps the table got torn down when you rebuild the container and you didn't recreate it in your start-up scripts. I've seen that happen. So you think it should be there, but in reality, it isn't.

Comment: @Hanny When I build my Docker it isn't rebuilding the db or the table. The db is company-wide and I'm just connecting to it when I build Docker. The db persists when I shut down Docker, it is not effected by Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Check the database name in settings.py, it should be 'sub' not 'tablename'.
Try this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'sub',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '1234',
    }
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same error, it says `psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "sub" does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled around and found that the configurations below finally worked for me.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'main',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=sub'
        },
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '1234',
    }
}
```

Thank you everyone for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You can open PGAdmin dashboard to review you database name and then change the correct database name, it worked!
The root cause of the issue is from wrong database name, so use the correct and try again, it fixed!

Answer (score -1):

Delete all your migrations file except for **init**.py file and then again run makemigrations, If migrate gives any error use -

python manage.py migrate --fake

This will fake the migrate process and you will be good to go.